# I have html like this.I want to compare anchor tag(href) and img src.If both href and src are same then it should not hyperlink.

Tags: php

```
<a href="http://dev.tone.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/israel-gaza-conflict-14.jpg">

<img class="size-medium wp-image-2820822" src="http://dev.tone.com/wp-

content/uploads/2014/07/israel-gaza-conflict-14.jpg" alt="ed over the Gaza Strip" width="300" 

height="200" /></a>

<a href="http://google.com"><img class="size-medium wp-image-2820817" 

src="http://dev.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/what-makes-people-happy1.jpg" 

alt="183023480" width="300" height="200" /></a>
```

If both href and src are same then it should not hyperlink.How can i do it by php

Comment: @fred compare each href with its image src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) its very easily possible.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$dox = new DOMXPath($doc);
$anchors = $dox->query("//a[./img]");
foreach($anchors as $anchor){
    $href = $anchor->getAttribute("href");
    $src = $anchor->getElementsByTagName("img")->item(0)->getAttribute("src");

    echo $href==$src? "equal": "not equal";
    echo "\n";
}
```

[Fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1iK77N)

Comment: Showing error as "Call to undefined method DOMXPath::xpath()" Please help

Comment: Ya thank you. I am sorry but i didn't asked the question correctly. my requirement is that if both are not same it should link to anchor tag(href) .And if both are same it should not link to anything. Can you tell how to do that

Comment: In that case change the attribute using the same api. Then just save the html. I have given you two links. There are examples inside those links.

Comment: Tried but not successful.Can you please show how to do